# Diagonalizability and triangularizability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let
$A \in M_3(\mathbb{R})$
and let $X= \{ C∈\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{R})|CAC^{−1}\text{ is triangular}\}$. Then

$A)$ $X \ne \emptyset$

$B)$ If $X=\emptyset$, then A is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

$C)$ If $X=\emptyset$, then A is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

$D)$ If $X=\emptyset$, then A has no real eigenvalues.

I know the concept of diagonalizability but I am unable to find the correct option in this question. Please provide me some hint/explanation on how to proceed in this question.

Comment: What were your efforts ?

Comment: I tried and somehow got that first option has to be incorrect as Every matrix order 3 is either diagonalizable or if not, then can be put in Jordan Canonical form which is traingular.

Comment: Hint : Since Jordan canonical normal form is a complete invariant for the conjugancy relation...

Comment: I am unable to grasp the hint. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Note that the [real Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices) is *not* triangular in general!

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the answer to this question is C.

If $A$ only has real eigenvalues, then $A$ has a Jordan canonical form with real entries, which means that $X$ is non-empty. So, if $X = \emptyset$, then $A$ must have at least one non-real eigenvalue.

Now, using the fact that the non-real eigenvalues of a real matrix come in conjugate pairs, conclude that the (complex) eigenvalues of $A$ must be distinct. Thus, $A$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: How you related the existence of real matrix C with eigenvalues of A? To be more precise, does existence of non real eigenvalues of A will always ensure the existence of a non-real matrix C such $CAC^{-1}$ is traingular ?

Comment: @ShashankDwivedi The existence of Jordan form is enough to tell you that there always exists a matrix $C$ with complex (possibly non-real) entries for which $CAC^{-1}$ is triangular. If the eigenvalues of $A$ happen to be real, then we can find such a $C$ with real entries. If $A$ has a non-real eigenvalue, then no such matrix exists